# Sitecore - How to Update FileDropAreaField Programmatically?

Tags: sitecore

Is there anyone who knows how to update filedropareafield programmatically in site-core and asp.net?

as per below code:

```
Prod.Editing.BeginEdit();
using (new EditContext(Prod))
{
     prod["image"]=
}
```

Comment: `FileDropArea` is a system field type. What do you want to achieve with this field? Are you should it's the type you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
        var database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
        var item = database.GetItem("{5306CEEC-AE8F-43D5-BA97-9F9551B2E50B}");
        var field = (FileDropAreaField)item.Fields["FileDropArea"];
        using (new EditContext(item))
        {
            var mediaCreator = new Resources.Media.MediaCreator();
            MediaItem mediaItem = mediaCreator.CreateFromFile("D:\\Images\\myimage.jpg",
                        new MediaCreatorOptions()
                        {
                            FileBased = false,
                            Database = database,
                            IncludeExtensionInItemName = false,
                            Versioned = false,
                            Destination = "/sitecore/media library/imagefolder/uploaded/myimage",
                            Language = Language.Parse("en")
                        });
            field.ChangeMediaFolder(database.GetItem("/sitecore/media library/imagefolder/uploaded"));
        }
```

[The answer on Sitecore community](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/4097)